# C++ Binary Tree With 3 Values For Struct

Tags: c++, struct, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

So I am attempting to create a binary search tree that stores an ID `(T value)` an age `(int age)` and a name `(string)` per each "bubble" located within the tree and is sorted by the ID.

For some reason, I cannot get my code to correctly store all 3 values as 1 structure per node. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here's my code.

```
#ifndef _TREE_GUARD 
#define _TREE_GUARD 1

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    int age;
    string name;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

    Node(T val) {
        this->value = val;
    }

    Node(T val, int age, string name, Node<T> left, Node<T> right) {
        this->value = val;
        this->age = age;
        this->name = name;

        this->left = left;
        this->right = right;
    }
};

template <class T>
class BST {

private:
    Node<T> *root;

    void addHelper(Node<T> *root, T val) {
        if (root->value > val) {
            if (!root->left) {
                root->left = new Node<T>(val);
            }
            else {
                addHelper(root->left, val);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!root->right) {
                root->right = new Node<T>(val);
            }
            else {
                addHelper(root->right, val);
            }
        }
    }

    void printHelper(Node<T> *root) {
        if (!root) return;
        printHelper(root->left);
        cout << root->value << ' ';
        cout << root->age << ' '; // ADDED
        cout << root->name << ' '; //ADDED
        printHelper(root->right);
    }

    int nodesCountHelper(Node<T> *root) {
        if (!root) return 0;
        else return 1 + nodesCountHelper(root->left) + nodesCountHelper(root->right);
    }

    int heightHelper(Node<T> *root) {
        if (!root) return 0;
        else return 1 + max(heightHelper(root->left), heightHelper(root->right));
    }

    void printMaxPathHelper(Node<T> *root) {
        if (!root) return;
        cout << root->value << ' ';
        if (heightHelper(root->left) > heightHelper(root->right)) {
            printMaxPathHelper(root->left);
        }
        else {
            printMaxPathHelper(root->right);
        }
    }

    bool deleteValueHelper(Node<T>* parent, Node<T>* current, T value) {
        if (!current) return false;
        if (current->value == value) {
            if (current->left == NULL || current->right == NULL) {
                Node<T>* temp = current->left;
                if (current->right) temp = current->right;
                if (parent) {
                    if (parent->left == current) {
                        parent->left = temp;
                    }
                    else {
                        parent->right = temp;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    this->root = temp;
                }
            }
            else {
                Node<T>* validSubs = current->right;
                while (validSubs->left) {
                    validSubs = validSubs->left;
                }
                T temp = current->value;
                current->value = validSubs->value;
                validSubs->value = temp;
                return deleteValueHelper(current, current->right, temp);
            }
            delete current;
            return true;
        }
        return deleteValueHelper(current, current->left, value) ||
            deleteValueHelper(current, current->right, value);
    }

public:

    void insert(T val) {
        if (root) {
            this->addHelper(root, val);
        }
        else {
            root = new Node<T>(val);
        }
    }

    void print() {
        printHelper(this->root);
    }

    int nodesCount() {
        return nodesCountHelper(root);
    }

    int height() {
        return heightHelper(this->root);
    }

    void printMaxPath() {
        printMaxPathHelper(this->root);
    }

    bool Delete(T value) {
        return this->deleteValueHelper(NULL, this->root, value);
    }
};
#endif
```

I created the struct using these 3 values, and a pointer to a right and left node, however, all my other functions don't seem to work with the age and name values, only the ID. This is most problamatic in my `add` and `print` function.

I'm relatively new to C++, so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm assuming my problem lies around here somewhere. The code runs just fine, but it doesn't add the age and name to the string, and I can't properly print these values, just the ID

```
 Node<T> *root;

    void addHelper(Node<T> *root, T val) {
        if (root->value > val) {
            if (!root->left) {
                root->left = new Node<T>(val);
            }
            else {
                addHelper(root->left, val);**
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!root->right) {
                root->right = new Node<T>(val);
            }
            else {
                addHelper(root->right, val);
            }
        }
    }
```

and here

```
void printHelper(Node<T> *root) {
        if (!root) return;
        printHelper(root->left);
        cout << root->value << ' ';
        cout << root->age << ' '; // ADDED
        cout << root->name << ' '; //ADDED
        printHelper(root->right);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you cut down the code into the snippet that creates the error, and what the error is?

Comment: @GillBates Tried my best to solidify the issue, and outlined my issue in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> root->left = new Node(val);
>
> root->right = new Node(val);

It seems that you create a new node and only give it a "val", no age, no name etc, so it only has the value.

edit: I never used "Template" before, so it took me a while to figure it out. Anyways...

Solution:
When you insert a node, you need to copy all the information, not just the "value", otherwise you'll only get the "value".

```
void addHelper(Node<T> *root, Node<T>* n) {
    if (root->value > n->value) {
        if (!root->left) {
            root->left = new Node<T>(n->value,n->age,n->name,NULL,NULL);
        }
        else {
            addHelper(root->left, n);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!root->right) {
            root->right = new Node<T>(n->value,n->age,n->name,NULL,NULL);
        }
        else {
            addHelper(root->right, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Also in "insert":

```
void insert(Node<T>* n) {
    if (root) {
        this->addHelper(root, n);
    }
    else {
        root = new Node<T>(n->value,n->age,n->name,NULL,NULL);
    }
}
```

Several other things you may try and see the difference:

I would initialize *root to be NULL, otherwise it may be some random stuff, and sometime I got seg fault because of that.

```
class BST {

private:
    Node<T> *root=NULL;
```

If the node you're about to insert has the same "value" with an already existing node, what do you do? Your program will just add it to the right. I don't know if that's what you want, but that's what it will do.

I tested with this and it worked. Hope it will work for you, too.

```
int main(){
    BST<int> tree;
    Node<int> node1(1,10,"test1",NULL,NULL);
    Node<int> node2(5,50,"test2",NULL,NULL);
    Node<int> node3(3,30,"test3",NULL,NULL);
    Node<int> node4(3,30,"test4",NULL,NULL);
    Node<int> node5(3,30,"test5",NULL,NULL);
    Node<int> node6(8,80,"test5",NULL,NULL);
    tree.insert(&node1);
    tree.insert(&node2);
    tree.insert(&node3);
    tree.insert(&node4);
    tree.insert(&node5);
    tree.insert(&node6);
    tree.print();
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1 10 test1 3 30 test3 3 30 test4 3 30 test5 5 50 test2 8 80 test5
```

Comment: So wait, removing <t> will fix this?

Comment: I dont understand this solution